# Besides 1099's, what other tax forms will I deal with as a freelancer (in the US)?

Tags: taxes

I'm just curious what other forms you need to deal with in the United States (Oregon for me) besides 1099's as a freelancer (sole proprietor). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how your freelance is configured.

For a sole proprietor taxes customarily involve:

- 1099s (If received, [but not required](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/should-i-expect-a-1099))
- 1040 (not 1040EZ)
- schedule C (deductions/expenses)

And taxes are paid in quarterly payments based upon these forms.

There may be more forms required for an S-Corp or other formal organization formation (articles of organization, meeting minutes, etc).

An actual freelance business can be created in many different forms. Each will have it's unique requirements.

Comment: There's nothing EZ about filing taxes as a freelancer... heh