# Do individuals hiring a US freelancer have to send a 1099?

Tags: taxes, canada

I was hired to do work for a Canadian author recently. I will be making over the $600 minimum to require a 1099.

Since this client does not own a business is he required to send me a 1099 at the start of the next year?

Additionally, would this differ based on the country of the client? This case if for a US worker and a CA client but what about cases of:

US client who doesn't own business -> US freelancer

UK client who doesn't own business -> US freelancer

I don't expect an answer from every countries perspective but the US, UK, and CA are where most of my clients/leads contact me from.

Comment: From a freelancer perspective... it does *not* matter. Freelancers are *not* required to include 1099s with their return, only *payees* are required to file them (if they want the deduction). See here: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/should-i-expect-a-1099

Answer (score 0):

The client is supposed to fill out the 1099-MISC to report the spending to the IRS. The reason a client is supposed to send *you* a *copy* of the 1099-MISC form is so that you have a formal record of the money they paid you to make it easier to do your own taxes. *You are required to report the income to the IRS whether or not you received a 1099-MISC for it.* I don't know whether someone outside of the US would be required to send the IRS a 1099-MISC if they hired a contractor inside the US.

Only one of the dozens of clients I have worked with has ever bothered to send me a 1099-MISC. You should ask for it directly if it's something you want, but consider yourself lucky if you ever receive one.